# Remove function removes all nodes in hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

I have this bit of code below to remove an entry from hash table. When I run the code, the program does not crash, but rather, all nodes in the specific bucket where I need to remove an element are all removed.
The count of inserted and removed elements is as it should be.

Sample

Before Remove.
Number of Nodes = 11

```
Bucket[0]
Node01, Node02, Node03

Bucket[1]
Node11, Node12, Node13, Node14

Bucket[2]
Node21, Node22

Bucket[3]
EMPTY

Bucket[4]
Node41, Node42
```

Remove `Node12`

Hash Table Becomes.
Number of Nodes = 10

```
Bucket[0]
Node01, Node02, Node03

Bucket[1]
EMPTY //This should be Node11, Node13, Node14

Bucket[2]
Node21, Node22

Bucket[3]
EMPTY

Bucket[4]
Node41, Node42
```

Remove Method

```
 void HashT::Remove(string key)
    {
        size_t index = HashFunc(key);
        if (table[index] != NULL)
        {
            node* prev = NULL;
            node* curr = table[index];
            while (curr->next != NULL && entry->item.GetKey() != key)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (curr->item.GetKey() == key)
            {
                node* nextEntry = curr->next;
                table[index] = nextEntry;
                delete entry;
                size--;
                cout << "Removed\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this function to insert into the hash table

```
void HashT::Ins(Data& data)
{
    size_t index = HashFunc(data.GetKey());
    node * newData = new node(data);
    if(table[index] != NULL && table[index]->item.GetKey() == data.GetKey())
        cout << "Do nothing\n";
    else
        newData->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newData;
        size++;
}
```

Calls to `Remove` inside main() looks something like this

```
HashT ht(cout);
ht.Ins(Data(node1));
ht.Ins(Data(node2));
ht.Ins(Data(node3));
ht.Ins(Data(node4));

ht.Remove("string3"); //This does not work

ht.Ins(Data(node5));
ht.Ins(Data(node6));
ht.Ins(Data(node7));
ht.Ins(Data(node8));

ht.Remove("string2"); //This Works
ht.Remove("string5"); //This doesnt work
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line?

Comment: Where and how is `entry` defined ?

Comment: @Christophe That was a typo. `entry` is `curr`. I update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose following change:

```
void HashT::Remove(string key)
    {
        size_t index = HashFunc(key);
        if (table[index] != NULL)
        {
            node* prev = NULL;
            node* curr = table[index];
            while (curr->next != NULL && entry->item.GetKey() != key)
            {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (curr->item.GetKey() == key) // change (1) !!!!
            {
                node* nextEntry = curr->next;
                if (prev)                      // change 2 !!!!
                   prev->next = nextEntry;     // change 2 !!!!
                else table[index] = nextEntry; // change 2 !!!
                delete entry;
                size--;
                cout << "Removed\n";
            }
            else if (curr->next!=NULL)            // change 1 !!!
                cout << "Not found in bucket\n";  // change 1 !!!
        }
    }
```

change 2 :  you shall update the table[index] only if the found element is the first in the bucket.  In all other case,  it's the classic removal of elements where you change the next pointer of the previous element to the next element (classic linked list update).

***Edit:*** my previous change 1 was mislead by the initial `entry`, sorry for that.  I've updated it to make explicit the cases where an item is not found in a bucket.

Comment: When I applied the changes, the first instance of `Remove` in `main.cpp` did not remove any node, but all nodes previously inserted were intact. Second call to `Remove` worked as it should.
Third call to `Remove` never worked, but nodes were intact.

Comment: Please see my edit in addition to my previous comment.

Comment: I added a sample main() in the question.

Comment: oops, this main doesn't correspond to the buckets displayed at the beginning of the question (different strings + different number of items).  If string3 and string5 are the last element of their bucket, my edit should have corrected the issue.  If not, please show the buckets as created by your main, for firther investigation :-)

Comment: Apologies, I just showed the order in which the calls was made. You recent update solved the problem.

Comment: PLEASE, can you briefly explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: The change 2 solved the issue: in fact you were cutting the bucket, keeping only what followed the deleted item.   The initial (wrong) change 1 caused the remove to ignore last elements of a bucket.